# How to replace string before string using regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
def f(float):
    tempstr = 0
    if float <= 0.5:
        tempstr = 'range1'
    if 0.6 <= float <= 1:
        tempstr = 'range2'
    if 1.1 <= float <= 2:
        tempstr = 'range3'
    if 2.1 <= float <= 3:
        tempstr = 'range4'
    if 3.1 <= integer <= 4:
        tempstr = 'range5'
    return(tempstr)
```

I have a string, I have to replace float which comes before cm with "range-i". There can be any number of spaces between the float and cm.

Example:-

string = 'this is 0.2 cm and that is 3.4   cm'

new_string = this is range1 cm and that is range5 cm (only one white space in between float and cm)

I want an efficient and simple solution using regex.

Comment: where is defined `integer`? An attempt on solving the problem would be useful... on both sides

Comment: in your example if `float` (bad variable naming btw) is > 4 (or any value between (1, 1.1), (2,2.1), (3,3.1) )you are returning an integer 0 instead of a string "rangeX". this looks very inconsistent since your function will return different data types depending on the range of `float`. If you later do string concatenation which expects a string this will fail when you provide an int.

Comment: It's not a good idea to name a parameter as `float` by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't shadow built-in functions, which means to call a variable with the same name of smt already defined, in this case `float()`, [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)... call it `float_` if you really lake of fantasy, ok?

More information on regex can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
s = 'this is 0.2 cm and that is 3.4 cm and now a 1.2 cm'

def f(float_):
    f = float(float_.group(1)) # casting the match result to float for comparison

    tempstr = '0' # <-- a string not an integer!
    if f <= 0.5:
        tempstr = 'range1'
    if 0.6 <= f <= 1:
        tempstr = 'range2'
    if 1.1 <= f <= 2:
        tempstr = 'range3'
    if 2.1 <= f <= 3:
        tempstr = 'range4'
    if 3.1 <= int(f) <= 4:
        tempstr = 'range5'
    return tempstr


import re

print(re.sub(r'(\d\.\d*)', f, s))
```

Output

```
this is range1 cm and that is 0 cm and now a range3 cm
```

Comment: could you run it with `s = 'this is 0.55 cm and that is 3.4 cm and now a 1.05 cm'`?

Comment: the boundaries are not continuous, I just assumed the 0 is fine... one can use `elif`s a catch them as exception

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there...

I would do:

```
def f(fl_):
    tempstr = '0'
    fl=float(fl_)
    if fl <= 0.5:
        tempstr = 'range1 '
    if 0.6 <= fl <= 1:
        tempstr = 'range2 '
    if 1.1 <= fl <= 2:
        tempstr = 'range3 '
    if 2.1 <= fl <= 3:
        tempstr = 'range4 '
    if 3.1 <= fl <= 4:
        tempstr = 'range5 '
    return(tempstr)

>>> string = 'this is 0.2 cm and that is 3.4 cm'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+\.\d+)\s+', lambda m: f(m.group(1)), string)
'this is range1 cm and that is range5 cm'
```

Note: There are discontinuities in your ranges such as `.55` and `1.05`. Is this intensional?

Answer (score 1):

If the range of float values in your script is assumed to be `0..4` then you just need to adjust a few things.

In the if statements, you are not checking the continuous ranges containing `0.5 to 0.6`, `1 to 1.1`, `2 to 2.1`, and `3 to 3.1`. Adjust each if statement to include the upper value of the previous range:

```py
if 0.5 < float <= 1:
```

You also had a NameError on `integer`, so this name was changed to the same as the other if statements.

This code below will encompass all values between 0 and 4:

```py
import re

def f(float_val):
    float_val = float(float_val.group(1))
    tempstr = 0
    if 0 <= float_val <= 0.5:
        tempstr = 'range1'
    if 0.5 < float_val <= 1:
        tempstr = 'range2'
    if 1 < float_val <= 2:
        tempstr = 'range3'
    if 2 < float_val <= 3:
        tempstr = 'range4'
    if 3 < float_val <= 4:
        tempstr = 'range5'
    return(tempstr)


s = 'this is 0.55 cm and that is 3.4 cm and now a 1.05 cm'
print(re.sub(r'(\d\.\d*)', f, s))
```